# Bootstrap column adjust to shorter column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I have a row and two columns. The first contains an image, the second some text. I'm trying to cut off the text at image height. Is this possible without JavaScript and fixed heights?

Thanks for your help!

```css
.row {
  margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem !important;
  max-width: 20rem;
}
div>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-5 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.col-7 {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* How do I make this column as tall as the previous? */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <img src="https://booklers.net/images/userImages/Doidel/bookImages/4/thumb.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-7">
    This is some test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to define a fixed `height`, otherwise the there's no reference point to determine what would be "overflowing" content

Comment: Ah, a pity. Thanks for your answer. Would you mind posting this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Do you want the text column to scroll?

Comment: Hmm doesn't matter, but it's not required. Probably I would make it hidden and on click show the full text, but for the sake of this demo it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner div on the text column and use `position:absolute`. Then set overflow-auto on both the column and inner div.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <img src="https://booklers.net/images/userImages/Doidel/bookImages/4/thumb.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-7 overflow-auto">
            <div class="scroll">
                This is some test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text. This is some more test text....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.scroll {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/zN6zQkyR4M

Comment: Oh well played madam, that's exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks a lot!
Would you mind adding the css .scroll to your answer too? For future reference :)